# How to get GRUB working dual boot Windows(Legacy) PopOS(UEFI)

Tags: grub, uefi, dualboot, pop-os, legacy

I've tried to get my dualboot screen working for a while, to give some context:

- I had the same Windows install for a few years now
- Installed PopOs a couple of months ago
- I have 2 drives and Windows is on my primary SSD and Pop!_OS on my HDD
- Got tierd of switching boot priority on BIOS to change from Windows to Pop!_OS
- Windows BIOS mode is on Legacy and Pop!_OS on UEFI

I followed this [guide](https://jacci.net/linux/pop-os/how-to-install-grub-on-pop-os-20-04/) but my grub isn't working properly, I've tried different boot entrys and found that:

- SATA6G_3: Samsung SS 850 EVO 2 **(Boots to Windows)**
- UEFI OS (SATA6G_5: Toshiba DT101ACA100) **(Boots to this [GRUB Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7kdl.jpg))**
- pop (SATA6G_5: Toshiba DT101ACA100) **(Boots to Pop!_Os)**
- Pop!_OS 20.10 (SATA6G_5: Toshiba DT101ACA100) **(Boots to Pop!_Os)**

**Note:** I've tried to use `sudo os-prober` to get the path for Windows but that command doesn't return any ouput (I did mount the SSD drive before running the comand)

I don't really know what is going on, I'm guessing that grub and Pop!_OS can't find Windows and that's why I'm having trouble

Comment: UEFI grub cannot chainload BIOS Windows Boot Manager. So *either* switch to BIOS grub or UEFI Windows Boot Manager.

Comment: to switch to BIOS grub I have to remove GRUB form my PopOS and install it on my SSD disk instead?

Answer (score 1):

From [Dual_boot_with_Windows](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dual_boot_with_Windows)

> **Most of the linux bootloaders installed for one firmware type cannot**
> **launch or chainload bootloaders of the other firmware type**. That is,
> if Arch is installed in UEFI/GPT or UEFI/MBR mode in one disk and
> Windows is installed in BIOS/MBR mode in another disk, the UEFI
> bootloader used by Arch cannot chainload the BIOS installed Windows in
> the other disk. Similarly if Arch is installed in BIOS/MBR or BIOS/GPT
> mode in one disk and Windows is installed in UEFI/GPT in another disk
> , the BIOS bootloader used by Arch cannot chainload UEFI installed
> Windows in the other disk.

> The only exceptions to this are GRUB in Apple Macs in which GRUB in
> UEFI mode can boot BIOS installed OS via appleloader command (does not
> work in non-Apple systems), and rEFInd which technically supports
> booting legacy BIOS OS from UEFI systems, but does not always work in
> [non-Apple UEFI systems as per its author Rod Smith](https://rodsbooks.com/refind/using.html#legacy).

Hence my suggestion : use [refind](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)

[pop-planet-REFInd](https://pop-planet.info/wiki/index.php?title=REFInd)

---

But there's more

> However if Arch is installed in BIOS/GPT in one disk and Windows is
> installed in BIOS/MBR mode in another disk, then the BIOS boot loader
> used by Arch CAN boot the Windows in the other disk, **if the boot**
> **loader itself has the ability to chainload from another disk.**

Comment: I don't know if there's more to it, but I did `sudo apt-get install refind` and on the startup screen no Windows logo was shown, I'm going to be honest, I didn't try every choice but since Windows didn't show up I thought that it wouldnt work either

Comment: @AndréClérigo try running : refind-install --alldrivers --usedefault /dev/sdXY ; replace XY with the device and partition number of the efi

Comment: @AndréClérigo it will create uefi entry refind, FYI refind scans for available entries and don't requires any configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Refind as your main bootloader. By default, it automatically checks all disks and partitions (all it can read that is) for .efi and vmlinux files. As far as I remember, it can boot both legacy and Uefi installed OSes, if your BIOS(UEFI) supports Legacy/CSM mode. But I think you need to uncomment the option in refind.conf file. (The info about this option is inside the .conf file itself, it's self-explanatory). And just in case your PC doesn't support it, it will explicitly tell you so during boot.